# Javac command returns "Invalid flag" when run from SHell script

Tags: bash, sh, javac

So I have a `.sh` script (in Ubuntu):

```
#!/bin/bash
javac betz2.java
```

When I run it, it says:

> Invalid flag: betz2.java

WHen run in terminal, it works just fine? why?

```
javac betz2.java
```

Comment: The answer is in a different post [Answer]
But google might take you here. [Answer]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583222/invalid-flag-error-when-using-bash-to-compile-java

Answer (score 0):

Maybe javac is not in the Bash path, but your command line is using a different shell that does have it. In your command line type `echo $SHELL` and you'll see if it is bash or not.

Did you edit your file in Windows and then opened it in a different operating system? (Linux). Carriage returns might be causing you trouble, just create a new file and paste your command.