# Invalid flag error when using bash to compile java

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to write a simple script to compile my java code.
When I put

```
javac Main.java
```

in my compile.sh and do

```
bash compile.sh
```

I get `error: invalid flag: Main.java`

However, if I just simply use the command `javac Main.java` , everything works fine.

I am using a Ubuntu VirtualBox on Win10.
How can I get my script working?

Comment: You will need to include more of your script.  It's not that line causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the problem you're seeing:

```
$ cat compile.sh
javac Main.java

$ bash compile.sh
javac: invalid flag: Main.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

This happens because the script uses DOS style line endings:

```
$ cat -v compile.sh
javac Main.java^M
```

You can fix it by setting your editor to save it with Unix line terminators, or with e.g. `tr`:

```
$ tr -d '\r' < compile.sh > fixed.sh
(no output)

$ cat -v fixed.sh
javac Main.java
```

It now works as expected:

```
$ bash fixed.sh
(no output)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have no idea that is a thing. I will keep an eye for that in the future.

Comment: I was using the same script the day before and it worked fine, for some reason the next day it started doing this. Thanks.